# Schema for D96A [Biztalk]

Tags: schema, biztalk, edifact

I need schema for EDIFACT files of document type "D-96A". I have BizTalk 2009 installed on my machine. But no schemas are available in the installation folder.

Is it available for download? or could anybody share the schemas for following

i) DESADV
b) INVRPT
c) ORDERSP
d) RECADV

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the BizTalk installation folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 R2\XSD_Schema\EDI`

You will find a file called: `MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates` unzip/install that file. This contains all **EDIFACT schemas**.

Comment: To clarify, it would be at %%\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2009\XSD_Schema\EDI\MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates.exe.  If you change the extension to .zip, you can browse it diretly and copy the schemas without unzipping the whole thing.

Comment: Hi, First thing is I am running Biztalk 2009 with VS 2005 installed.

  Secondly, I neither find XSD_Schema nor MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates in my installation folder. [since "Developer tools and SDK" option was not available during installation]  I believe that XSD_Schema folder will be created only when "Developer tools and SDK" is selected during installation

  And finally, Now I am installing VS 2008 and sp1 and hope that XSD_Schema would be available after re-installing Biztalk 2009.

Anyways I'll keep you all posted and thank you very much for all your efforts

Comment: Hi Glenn and boatseller, as you ppl said the file MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates is created after re-installing BTS 2009 with VS 2008 sp1 installed in the machine. Thank you very much